# Make my asyncForEach() Parallel Instead of Sequential

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

So I want the code inside loop to run simultaneously but the code after the loop to run only when loop is done processing:

## Code

```js
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

const waitFor = (ms, num) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(num)
  r()
}, ms));

const doStuff = async() => {

  await asyncForEach([1, 2, 3], async(num) => {
    await waitFor(1000, num);
  })

  console.log('Done');
}

doStuff()
```

## Output

```
/* Output
1   - takes 1 sec
2   - takes 1 sec
3   - takes 1 sec
Done
    - total 3 sec
*/
```

## What I want

```
/* What I want
    _
1    |
2    | - takes 1 sec
3   _|
Done
    - total 1 sec
*/
```

Comment: Please don't work around the rules of the site by putting in extraneous characters so that your title is one character different from another. Instead, read [ask] and come up with a better title that more uniquely describes your specific question, or better yet, read the other questions to see if yours might have been asked before.

Comment: Javascript is a `single-threaded language`. This means it has one call stack and one memory heap.      

You can not achieve what You want in JS. Each function is called one by one but in the event loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I made the title more descriptive, just as an example for them to use in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
  await Promise.all(
    array.map(callback)
  );
};

const waitFor = (ms, num) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(num);
    resolve();
  }, ms);
});

const doStuff = async () => {
  await asyncForEach([1, 2, 3], async num => {
    await waitFor(1000, num);
  });

  console.log('Done');
};

doStuff();
```

Comment: NB: your `callback` function will be invoked with the additional parameters that `map` always passes to callbacks.  Ensure that the called function won't misbehave as a result (c.f. the behaviour of `parseInt` with `map`)

Comment: p.s. `asyncForEach` here doesn't strictly need to be tagged `async` because it does not call anything with `await` and will always return a `Promise`.

Comment: @Alnitak note the callback is invoked with the same parameters in the question. The `async` doesn't need to be there, but seeing as this is a `asyncForEach` and not an `asyncMap`, I should change it anyway to not return an array in the promise resolution.

Comment: Ooos, yes, didn't spot myself that the OP was replicating the `forEach` callback parameter structure, although that comment was more intended for other readers than for you.