# Javascript: mixed serial and parallel processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am looking for a ES6 solution for my problem (which can be quite common, I suppose...):

I have a list of remote providers each publishing a list of items on one page, and each item details on other pages.
I need to fetch all items details from all providers, once per hour (say).

I would like to fetch all providers lists in parallel, and, as soon as each of the lists is resolved, fetch all items details from that list, in parallel (I will throttle the requests as needed to avoid `ECONNRESET` errors, but this is another story).

This is an implementation of my tentative solution:

```js
    const providers = [
      {
        name: 'A',
        urlList: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?_start=0&_limit=1',
        urlItem: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=%id%&_start=0&_limit=2',
      },
      {
        name: 'B',
        urlList: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?_start=2&_limit=2',
        urlItem: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=%id%&_start=0&_limit=2',
      },
      {
        name: 'C',
        urlList: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?_start=4&_limit=2',
        urlItem: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=%id%&_start=0&_limit=2',
      },
    ];
    
    const getList = (provider) => fetch(provider.urlList).then(res => res.json());
    
    const getItems = (provider, list) => Promise.all(
      list.map(item => {
        return fetch(provider.urlItem.replace("%id%", item.id)).then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.map(r => ({ provider: provider.name, name: item.name, ...r })));
      })
    );
    
    const providerFetch = async provider => {
      console.log(`providerFetch ${provider.name} start`);
      try {
        const list = await getList(provider);
        const items = await getItems(provider, list);
        return items;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`providerFetch ${provider.name} error: ${error}`);
      } finally {
        console.log(`providerFetch ${provider.name} done`);
      }
    }
    
    (async () => {
      console.log('start');
      const data = await Promise.all(
        providers.map(async provider => {
          const providerData = providerFetch(provider);
          return providerData;
        })
      );
      //console.dir(data, { depth: 3 });
      console.log(data.flat(2));
      console.log('end');
    })();
```

It sports at least two issues:

1. I am using `Promise.all()` twice, so I get a 3 dimensional array, while I'd prefer a simple one dimensional array... Is there a way to let `Promise.all()` to concat promises results and not to push them?
2. The most serious issue: I am fetching all the providers lists, and, only when all of them are ready, I start fetching the items (in parallel, as expected). Instead, I want to start fetching items for each list as soon the list is fetched. Can you give me some hint how to change my code to achieve it?

**UPDATE**:
Thanks also to @Bergi's comments, I could understand that:

- point 1.: this can be simply solved using a `flat(2)` (2 is the depth to be flattened out) on the final data; the solution is not so sleek, but it looks like `promise.All()` can only push, and not concat. I did change my code sample to show it.
- point 2.: the fact that the `providerFetch` was working serially was only an assumption of mine, probably due to the fact that `getList`s are so fast in this test code... In fact, adding a delay before the `getList` returns, I can see some `getItems` do start before all the `getLists` are finished.

Comment: check this out...
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63173059/10872163

Comment: "*I am fetching all the providers lists, and, only when all of them are ready, I start fetching the items*" - um, no, you don't. Your `providerFetch` is calling `getItems` immediately after the `getList` is completed. Nothing in your code waits for all the lists.

Comment: "*I am using `Promise.all()` twice, so I get a 3 dimensional array*" - nesting two `Promise.all`s gets you a two-dimensional array. The third dimension comes from `getItems` fetching an array.

Comment: "*Is there a way to let `Promise.all()` concat promises results*" - no, there's not, but it's trivial to flatten the nested array after the `Promise.all()` promise fulfilled (in a `.then` callback or after `await`).

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` itself doesn't have a concat feature but javascript arrays do. So just concat the result afterwards:

```
const result = await Promise.all(/* your original code ... */);

let data = [];

result.forEach(x => data = data.concat(x));

// now data is as you expect
```

Comment: `providerFetch` does not (and cannot) return an array

Comment: @Bergi Haven't finished writing answer

Comment: @Bergi Didn't notice it's waiting for two promises in series